# Flutter, dart index

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an index value in my project, but when I run the application, the index value starts at 0. I want it to start as 1, what should I do?

```
tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
return CupertinoTabView(
builder: (BuildContext context){
return CupertinoPageScaffold(
navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
middle: Text('Page 1 of tab $index'),
backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
),
```

Comment: indexes start at 0. You can add 1 where you really need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array starts at 0 in dart.
if you want your UI to display 1 at first position or add 1 to every position then you can use `index+1`

```
tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
return CupertinoTabView(
builder: (BuildContext context){
return CupertinoPageScaffold(
navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
middle: Text('Page 1 of tab ${index+1}'), // add +1 to your index here
backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
),
```